# I need help with a airless inner tube/tire issue

Tags: tire, wheels, innertube

So I just bought a brand new Abound from Aventon. The city I live in is horrible and even with double thick tired, Tannus armor inserts, and puncture-resistant inner tubes I've had 3 flats in 3 months from nails, needles, and other unknown horrors.

I started looking into airless tires and airless innertubes but I can't seem to find any that would fit my bike. My abound currently uses a 20x2.40 tire. So 2 part question here,

1.) Does anyone know where I could buy airless tube inserts that will fit my tire size? The largest I've been able to find was 20x1.95 inserts and they didn't fit.

2. Does anyone know if I could change the tire size on by abound and be okay? I know I can get inserts in the size of 20x1.95 so theoretically could I just buy some 20x2.0 rims and be good using them?

Comment: Have you considered tubeless, or 'slimed' tubes?